# eclipse rcp change icon for xml configuration file

Tags: xml, eclipse, icons, rcp

I built an Eclipse RCP application that uses the `configuration.xml` in the root of the project for some project configurations. I would like to customize the icon and keep default xml editor. I found one blog [post](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2008/04/content-type-specific-file-icons.html), that does exactly what I'm looking for a `property` file. I extracted it:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
  <content-type base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.properties"
    file-extensions="config"
    id="in.cypal.eclipse.myConfig"
    name="My Config File"
    priority="normal">
  </content-type>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.propertiesfileeditor.PropertiesFileEditor"
    default="false"
    extensions="config"
    icon="icons/sample.gif"
    id="in.cypal.eclipse.editors.myConfigEditor"
    name="My Config Editor">
      <contentTypeBinding contentTypeId="in.cypal.eclipse.myConfig">
      </contentTypeBinding>
  </editor>
</extension>
```

I guess that I basically need to adjust the attribute `class` of the `editor` element to the implementation of the xml editor in Eclipse. I installed the `org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group`. I'm not able to find the right implementation. Please help :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could to solve my problem, here is my solution if someone should have the same issue.

```
 <extension
        point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
     <content-type
           base-type="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml"
           file-names="configuration.xml"
           id="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml.spl"
           name="Software Product Line Configuration"
           priority="normal">
     </content-type>
  </extension>
  <extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
     <editor
           class="org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart"
           default="true"
           icon="icons/configuration.png"
           id="YOUR_ID"
           name="Software Product Line Configuration">
        <contentTypeBinding
              contentTypeId="org.eclipse.core.runtime.xml.spl">
        </contentTypeBinding>
     </editor>
  </extension>
```

I imported the `org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui` bundle to my workspace and had a look into Extension tab in the `MANIFEST.MF` file. The extension point `org.eclipse.ui.editors` appeared just one. So I used the implementation in the `class` attribute and it worked :)

**Edit**: If I would have known about the [Eclipse Plugin Spy](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/06/22/eclipse-plug-in-spy-eclipse-rcp/), this would have been easier. So, if a feature is already present, just use the magic shortcut to figure out the implementation details :)